# Не происходит запись в БД sqlite (php)

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, insert

Не происходит запись данных формы в БД. Не могу понять почему.
Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка?

Данные в массив $_POST записываются, вижу в консоли браузера. А в БД данные не появляются. 
Ошибок никаких не возникает (не вижу их в журнале ошибок на сервере).

Поправьте, пожалуйста, что я неправильно делаю?

Код такой:

```
<?php

$user_id;
$user_name;
$login;
$password;
$repassword;
$phone;
$role;

if(isset($_POST['user_id'])) {$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];} 
if(isset($_POST['user_name'])) {$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];};
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {$login = $_POST['login'];};
if(isset($_POST['password'])) {$password = $_POST['password'];};
if(isset($_POST['repassword'])) {$repassword = $_POST['repassword'];};
if(isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];};
if(isset($_POST['role'])) {$role = $_POST['role'];};



$new = new PDO('sqlite:'.__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test.sqlite3; host=localhost', 'admin', 'qwerty');


$stmt=$new->exec("INSERT INTO board_users (user_id,login,password,phone,role,user_name) VALUES     
('$user_id','$login','$password','$phone','$role','$user_name')");
?>
```

Пробовала так тоже:

```
$stmt = $new->prepare("INSERT INTO board_users (user_id,login,password,phone,role,user_name) VALUES 
('$user_id','$login','$password','$phone','$role','$user_name')");

$stmt=$new->exec();
```

Comment: Права на запись в базу test.sqlite3 и в папку где лежит этот файл, имеются у пользователя из под которого запускаются скрипты?

Comment: Вот, сейчас буду выяснять у хостера этот вопрос. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате выяснилось, что для записи в БД sqlite через PDO нужно было просто убрать хост и данные авторизации. И все заработало.

Вот такой вариант рабочий:

```
$new = new PDO('sqlite:'.__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test.sqlite3');
```

Answer (score -1):

Вас не смущает что сохраняемые переменные в одинарных кавычках?
Переделайте на это:

```
    $stmt = $new->prepare("INSERT INTO board_users (user_id,login,password,phone,role,user_name) VALUES ($user_id,$login,$password,$phone,$role,$user_name)");
```

Лучше вообще делать экранирование и проверять параметры. К примеру:

```
$stmt = $new->prepare("INSERT INTO board_users (user_id,login,password,phone,role,user_name) VALUES (:user_id,:login,:password,:phone,:role,:user_name)");
$stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
...//остальные параметры
$stmt ->execute();
```

Comment: Я пробовала и с кавычками и без оных. И с bindParam, и с bindValue. Не добавляется в БД ничего. Мне, вот, пришло в голову, что, возможно, какие-то права скрипту требуется установить. Попробую, отпишусь.